# Change relative URL to absolute within a PHP include

Tags: php, perl

I have a calendar application where the calendar will show one month per page, with navigation for each month.

I want to include this calendar in our templates. I can easily do so with a PHP include.

However, within the iframe, the calendar uses relative links to get to the other months. I need to set these to absolute links.

I am wondering if I can use JavaScript, or perhaps a PHP function to replace the links, but within the include?

The calendar itself is written in Perl, and runs from our cgi-bin. It is included using

```
<?php include('http://pps.servername.edu/cgi-bin/calendarappname/calendar.pl?Op=ShowIt&CalendarName=thename'); ?>
```

the links on the calendar that I wish to change appear like this

```
<a href="Calendar.pl?CalendarName=nameofcalendar&amp;Op=ShowIt&amp;Amount=Month&amp;NavType=Absolute&amp;Type=Block&amp;Date=2014%2F3%2F1">2014</a>
```

I was thinking of doing a string replace or preg_replace, but I wasn't sure what would work, given that the URLs to be changed appear in a PHP include.

Comment: You need to change the links inside the calendar application not the path in the include. You need to reword your question.

Comment: I cant change the paths in the calendar app, at least not natively. I was hoping to dynamically change the links when I loaded the include.

Comment: @LisaH I think it's relevant to ask why you want to change all the hrefs to be absolute urls instead of relative?  maybe this is an [`XY Problem`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: @Miller- thanks for asking. Each calendar displays the current month. To view the upcoming months, users can click a link to view that month. Right now, the links result in a 404 error, because the calendar links are relative to the position of the including page, and they need to be within the calendar app itself, which is in the cgi-bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `include()` the calendar; `fopen()` it and read it into a string. (Or use `file_get_contents()` which does the open, read, and close in one step.)

Once you have a string, you can manipulate it however you like, and then `print()` it.

Comment: can you give me a code example. I like this approach

Comment: That is, I get the file_get_contents() part... I can do that, but how would I ask to change urls?

Comment: Using `preg_replace` or `str_replace` like you said in your question. It's a string, so you can apply arbitrary string manipulation.